# Firebase node.js remove item from dictionary

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can successfully add and fetch values from my firebase database.

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
// Get a reference to the database service
var database = firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref();
var refer = database.ref('todo');
```

I have a todo list in my database, I wanted use an array but from what I understand firebase doesnt prefer arrays.

So I just add values to my todo list like

```
function handleAddTodoIntent(intent, session, response) {
    refer.push(todoSlot.value);
}
```

and it works

[image]

But when I try to remove the items , it seems it doesnt do anything

`refer.remove();` removes entire `todo` dictionary and `refer.child(todoSlot.value).remove();` seems not deleting the value from database.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: How do you know what item to delete? I assume you have some condition that determines what TODO item you want to delete. Or do you assume the values are unique (in which case you can use them to determine your key)?

Comment: so the data in` todo` is chronological right? so second item would be "Walk the dog", if user says delete the second item, I wanna delete walk the dog. Obviously it is not the best practice because values can be  same in multiple children but I am just trying to learn this, also I dont store uniqiue ids in the .js file , it is just a facade to delete/add items

Comment: Especially in a multi-user distributed system there are no guarantees of what "the second item" is. If you want to delete a specific item, you have to keep the key (the thing start with `-K`) of that item.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is `refer.child(todoSlot.value)`.
You are referencing the wrong path. `child()` should take the name of the field, not a value.
When you push a new child, you can get its key by following:
`var todoSlotKey = refer.push(todoSlot.value);`
And if you just want to remove the pushed `todoSlot.value`,  you can simply do:    `refer.child(todoSlotKey).remove();`